# Android Studio - CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja". CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, build.gradle

I'm going crazy with this error. I have tried searching and changing my code according to some suggestions that can be found in stackoverflow but still get the same error.
I have downloaded CMake and there's Ninja in it. There's no LLDB.

[My Ninja's path inside CMake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcHuL.png)

[My Android Studio SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npZzQ.png)

Here's the build.gradle. The comments are what I've tried

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.opencv"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                //cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
//                arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + project(':opencv').projectDir + "/native/jni",
//                        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared",
//                        "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang"
                //cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                //arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                //abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
                arguments "-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja"
            }
        }
//        ndk {
//            moduleName "native-lib"
//            abiFilters "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master>gradlew build --stacktrace

> Configure project :app
Support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature. To report a bug, see https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html
Support for CMake 3.7 and higher is a preview feature. To report a bug, see https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html

> Task :app:generateJsonModelDebug FAILED
External native generate JSON debug: starting JSON generation
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 21 for ABI ARMEABI_V7A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON debug: rebuilding JSON D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json due to:
External native generate JSON debug: - expected json D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\android_gradle_build.json file is not pre
sent, will remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON debug: - missing previous command file D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\cmake_build_command.txt,
will remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON debug: removing stale contents from 'D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'
External native generate JSON debug: created folder 'D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'
External native generate JSON debug: executing cmake Executable : D:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
arguments :
-HD:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\src\main\cpp
-BD:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DANDROID_NDK=D:\Android\sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=D:\Android\sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Android\sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
-G Ninja
-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja
jvmArgs :




[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"supportedProtocolVersions":[{"isExperimental":true,"major":1,"minor":1}],"type":"hello"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{
  "type": "handshake",
  "cookie": "gradle-cmake-cookie",
  "protocolVersion": {
    "isExperimental": true,
    "major": 1,
    "minor": 1
  },
  "sourceDirectory": "D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/src/main/cpp",
  "buildDirectory": "D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a",
  "generator": "Ninja"
}

]== "CMake Server" ==]



[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"gradle-cmake-cookie","inReplyTo":"handshake","type":"reply"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

[== "CMake Server" ==[

{
  "type": "configure",
  "cacheArguments": [
    "",
    "-DANDROID_ABI\u003darmeabi-v7a",
    "-DANDROID_PLATFORM\u003dandroid-21",
    "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY\u003dD:\\Android_OCR\\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cmake\\debug\\obj\\armeabi-v7a",
    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE\u003dDebug",
    "-DANDROID_NDK\u003dD:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\21.3.6528147",
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS\u003d",
    "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME\u003dAndroid",
    "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI\u003darmeabi-v7a",
    "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION\u003d21",
    "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS\u003dON",
    "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK\u003dD:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\21.3.6528147",
    "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE\u003dD:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\21.3.6528147\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake",
    "-G Ninja",
    "-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja"
  ]
}

]== "CMake Server" ==]



[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to \"Ninja\".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to
select a different build tool.","title":"Error","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.


[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","progressCurrent":1000,"progressMaximum":1000,"progressMessage":"Configuring","progressMinimum":0,"type":"progress"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]



[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!\nSee also \"D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armea
bi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log\".","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","errorMessage":"Configuration failed.","inReplyTo":"configure","type":"error"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

Configuration failed.
External native generate JSON debug: using platform version 21 for ABI ARM64_V8A and min SDK version 21
External native generate JSON debug: rebuilding JSON D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json due to:
External native generate JSON debug: - expected json D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json file is not prese
nt, will remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON debug: - missing previous command file D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a\cmake_build_command.txt, wi
ll remove stale json folder
External native generate JSON debug: removing stale contents from 'D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a'
External native generate JSON debug: created folder 'D:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a'
External native generate JSON debug: executing cmake Executable : D:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
arguments :
-HD:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\src\main\cpp
-BD:\Android_OCR\OpenCVTesseractOcr-master\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a





... *[I cut it. Too much stacktrace and it's looping]*






]== "CMake Server" ==]



[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to \"Ninja\".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to
select a different build tool.","title":"Error","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.


[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","progressCurrent":1000,"progressMaximum":1000,"progressMessage":"Configuring","progressMinimum":0,"type":"progress"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]



[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","inReplyTo":"configure","message":"Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!\nSee also \"D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_6
4/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log\".","type":"message"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Android_OCR/OpenCVTesseractOcr-master/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".


[== "CMake Server" ==[

{"cookie":"","errorMessage":"Configuration failed.","inReplyTo":"configure","type":"error"}

]== "CMake Server" ==]

Configuration failed.
External native generate JSON debug: JSON generation completed with problems

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error configuring

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:131)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:343)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:212)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error configuring
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 110 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error configuring
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.executeProcessAndGetOutput(CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:198)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.CmakeExternalNativeJsonGenerator.executeProcess(CmakeExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:126)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.buildAndPropagateException(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:323)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.build(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:188)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.build(ExternalNativeBuildJsonTask.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        ... 123 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
23 actionable tasks: 23 executed
```

--- EDIT CMakeList.txt ---
[Sorry. Turns out I deleted too much because of the limit...]

And here's CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Am I missing something?
I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

For me removing from project .cxx folder worked

Answer (score 1):

In order to make ninja work you need to add before the `-G` parameter the following
`DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` path.

Below is the full batch script you can use.

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Aeon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Aeon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147 -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Aeon\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions "C:\DLib"
cmake --build
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CMake file looks dismantled; nothing will build successfully by using it in this state. Typically for NDK projects, I've seen template CMakeLists.txt files containing CMake code for the `native-lib` and `log-lib` libraries. This template is a good place to start.

To get you half-way there, consider changing your CMake code to the following, or switching to use the template laid out in [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake) tutorial:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Specify the 'native-lib' library
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)

# Find the log NDK library.
find_library(log-lib log)

# Link the log library to the native-lib library.
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib})
```

I recommend spending some time to get familiar with CMake, and how to construct basic CMake files. The tutorials in the `cmake` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmake/info) has lots of helpful info.

Comment: Still the same error... Is it the log-lib? (I mean, is it generated automatically or do I need to download it?)